# node.js - after get request, script does not return to console

Tags: node.js, http

Here is a simple script

```
    var http = require("http");

    http.get( WEBSITE, function(res) {
       console.log("Does not return");
       return;
    });
```

if `WEBSITE` variable is 'http://google.com' or 'http://facebook.com' script does not return to console.
but if `WEBSITE` variable is 'http://yahoo.com' or 'http://wikipedia.org' it returns to console. What is the difference?

Comment: Are you suggesting that the `return` statement at the end should exit the program?  It just returns out of the function, which is redundant at that point.  There must be more to your program.  Node exits when the event loop has nothing to do.  Therefore, there must be a pending timer or I/O operation.  You need to share more of your program's code for troubleshooting.

Comment: There is nothing in my script except above shown code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By "return to console" I'm assuming you mean that node exits and drops you back at a shell prompt.

In fact, node does *eventually* exit for all of those domains you listed.  (You were just impatient.)

What you are seeing is the result of HTTP keep-alives.  By default, node keeps the TCP connection open after a HTTP request completes.  This makes subsequent requests to the same server faster.  As long as a TCP connection is still open, node will not exit.

Eventually, either node or the server will close the idle connection (and thus node will exit).  It's likely that Google and Facebook allow idle connections to live for longer amounts of time than Yahoo and Wikipedia.

If you want your script to make a request and exit as soon as it completes, you need to disable HTTP keep-alives.  You can do this by disabling [Agent](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent) support.

```
http.get({ host:'google.com', port:80, path:'/', agent:false }, function(res) {
   ...
});
```

Only disable the Agent if you need this specific functionality.  In a normal, long-running app, disabling the Agent can cause many problems.

There are also [some other approaches you can take to avoid keep-alives keeping node running](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23703310/201952).