# Node app doesn't terminate after web request?

Tags: node.js

I'm reading IDs from a text file and making some RESTful requests. It works, but when all IDs have been run, the node app stays running.

main.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');

var ids = fs.readFileSync('test.txt', { encoding: 'utf8' });
ids = ids.split('\n');
var options = {
    hostname: 'internalhost',
    port: 80,
    path: '',
    method: 'DELETE'
};
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    options.path = '/thing/' + ids[i];
    console.log('Deleting thing ' + ids[i]);

    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
        console.log('Status: ' + res.statusCode);
    });

    req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('Problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });

    req.end();
}
```

The requests are made successfully but after the last one, the app continues to run. I've tried adding `res.end()` right after I print the response's status code, but then I get an error that `res` doesn't have a method `end`.

What's going on here?

Comment: You're probably having the same [problem seen here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23068327/201952).

Comment: @josh3736 The problem is that all my requests are to the same server and can benefit from keep-alive being kept on. I may have to fall back to Explosion Pills answer because of that.

Answer (score 3):

It appears you're [suffering from a side-effect of HTTP keep-alives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23068327/201952).  Node does not exit when there are TCP connections open, and the [HTTP `Agent`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent) leaves TCP connections open for an indefinite amount of time.

You've mentioned that keep-alives will be beneficial for you, so your options are limited.

- Simply disabling the `Agent` will result in keep-alives being disabled, so this isn't really an option.
- You can manually manage and track your requests, and when all have been completed, call `process.exit`.  I don't like this, however, as it is a rather blunt instrument.  If you have other async operations running (such as DB calls), you may accidentally end your app before those operations complete.
- You can manually manage and track your requests.  When all have been completed, you can loop through the `Agent` instance's `sockets` property and close all lingering sockets. (**Warning**: [calling `close` on an already closed socket throws](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/7295).)

  This is a much safer approach because other outstanding operations will be allowed to finish before the app exits.
- You could upgrade to node ≥ 0.11.4.  (Realistically, you'd probably want to wait until 0.12 stable is released.)  The next node version has a [greatly improved `Agent` implementation](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/9fc9b87472806147b83c24d85b303c4f75d3021c) that [`unref`](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_unref)s idle sockets kept in the `Agent`'s connection pool.  In other words, node can exit if the only open TCP connections are those being held for reuse as a keep-alive connection.
- You could also rip out the [new `Agent` implemention](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_http_agent.js) from the unstable branch and use it for your app's requests instead of the default `Agent` provided by your version of node.  *(This is probably what I'd do.)*

Comment: Thanks @josh3736, useful piece of information of upgrading to ≥ 0.11.4, fixed my problem!

Answer (score 2):

node will only terminate if there are no pending events to be handled. In this case I believe the connection is still open, so you can either destroy it manually by calling `res.socket.end()` or `res.destroy()` or as @ExplosionPills Suggested, just call `process.exit` when all requests are done. You can use `async` module to help you to achieve this.

Comment: I like this. No keeping count, no open ended connections. Simple and effective.

Comment: Closing the socket as soon as you get the response has the same effect as disabling the Agent -- you lose the benefits of HTTP keep-alives.

Comment: @josh3736 I was just about to come back and ask about that (destroying the keep alive). Is there no "best of both worlds" way to do this?

Comment: @CoreyOgburn: Yes, but unfortunately nothing that's particularly clean or straightforward.  See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23703310/201952).