# NodeJS - HTTP request doesn't return handle to REPL

Tags: node.js

I have the following code returning 200, but the handle on Node REPL doesn't get returned

```
require('https').get('https://www.google.com/', (resp)=>{console.log(resp.statusCode)}).end();
```

It shows

> 200

But then it's waiting and doesn't return the handle until I press ENTER. Does this mean I have missed adding some directive?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here. If the script is used as agent mode, the connection is kept-alive. A similar issue was posted here

[node.js - after get request, script does not return to console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23068327/node-js-after-get-request-script-does-not-return-to-console)

when I tried with `agent:false`- and provided `host, port, path` information as well - it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

Work code is sounds, but REPL (and callbacks) are toying with you...

It actually does return the "handle"... it's just *looking* like it is not in REPL.

"console.log(param)" return the string parameter (ie:200, in this case), at stdout(the console) WITH A RETURN LINE. Thus giving the illusion that you are between command lines... you are not... you could type the next command instead on pressing "ENTER", and it would work.

To demonstrate better, try running your code with separate lines, and try to type a command "before handle return".

```
const https = require('https');
var req = https.get('https://www.google.com/', (resp)=>{console.log(resp.statusCode)});
req.end();
```

[image]